# Find a s-grammar (simple grammar)

Tags: automata, ambiguous-grammar

find a simple grammar (a.k.a s-grammar) for the following language:

L={(ab)<sup>2m</sup>b :m>=0}

[i did this but it is wrong]

S-> aASBB|b

A-> a

B->b

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
S -> aA | T
A -> bB
B -> aC
C -> bS
T -> b
```

This is a regular grammar - all productions of the form `X -> sY` or `X -> t`, and corresponds to a minimal DFA for the language in question via a direct mapping of productions to transactions and nonterminal symbols to states.

Answer (score 0):

How about
`S->aAb|b A->aAb|bB B->lambda`